# npm whitesource not getting installed

Tags: angular-cli, npm-install

I tried to install whitesource through npm. I ran the following command

`npm install whitesource --save`

After installing I checked on package.json and whitesource was available. I then ran the following command to check if the dependencies are installed correctly.

`npm list --depth=0`

The output confirmed the presence of whitesource. I then navigated to node_modules and found the folder whitesource with bin directories.

Now when I try to run 
`whitesource run`
I get the error: 
`$ whitesource run
-bash: whitesource: command not found`

Any suggestions how to debug or fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Please run

```
npm i -g whitesource
```

You've installed the WhiteSource package as a project dependency, not as a global package. (That's what the "-g" is for).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can install and check the path of Whitesource:

$ npm install -g whitesource

$ which whitesource

After that you can create the alias and then run whitesource

$ alias whitesource="node path/to/whitesource"

$ whitesource run

[Whitesource Doc reference for NPM Plugin](https://whitesource.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/WD/pages/34209870/NPM+Plugin)